# Changing DNS of the EC2 instance of a live site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, hosting, amazon-route53

We bought our domain from Godaddy.com, then we changed the nameservers with the ones we got from Amazon 53. This name server shifting took around 30-40 hours.

In route 53, we used the Elastic IP of 1st EC2 instance A Name, Ipv4 address to host our mydomain.com website.

Then we had to shift our framework so we were testing on with another EC2 instance on mydomain.in website. After we successfully tested, we tried to route the new web server on mydomain.com by changing the IP address in Route 53 with the Public IP of 2nd EC2 instance, so that the mydomain.com points to the tested and ready 2nd Ec2 instance.

But the IP at route 53 for mydomain.com didn't happen immediately as in case of mydomain.in whose IP we replaced on the Godaddy site with the IP Address of 2nd instance. 
Due to the release of our product, we couldn't risk taking the mydomain.com offline by initiating the nameservers change on Godaddy.com to the original nameservers.

Currently we are redirectly all our mydomain.com hits to our mydomain.in website which we want to stop doing after a while.

Is there a way where we can route our mydomain.com to the 2nd EC2 instance without having a long downtime?

Is there a quickfix in the route 53 console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check your TTL settings in your DNS.

If you TTL is set to a very high-level, than you are instructing browsers that they only need to re-resolve the Domain to the IP address very infrequently.

If you know you are planning on changing the the IP address, best to plan in advance.

Make note of your current TTL value - say for example it is set to 86400 seconds (24 hours). At least 24 hours before you want to change your DNS, drop the TTL down to something like 300 (5 minutes).

After you want at least 24 hours (so that everyone who has resolved your domain within the TTL period has been given the new, lower TTL value, then you can swap your IP in route 53. Because you lowered your TTL down to 5 minutes, and because you waited a while to let the value propgate, this DNS address change should happen quickly, i.e. within 300 seconds.

After a bit of day (a few hours or days), you can increase the TTL again if you don't plan on moving it again soon - to allow for longer caching of the domain to ip transaltion.

Route 53 isn't the problem here, generally speaking, when I make DNS changes in Route 53 I can get websites resolving at a new location in a handful of minutes.

Comment: I have successfully changed the domains